# Cannot Output Data Into a Text File

Tags: c++

I am experimenting with some code for outputting information to a file.  The file address appears to be correct and the code compiles but the file never populates.  Can you see a problem?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size = 10;
for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
{
    ofstream outputfile;
    outputfile.open("C:MyFolder\outputfile.txt", ios::app);
    outputfile << "SYMBOL, STOCK_PRICE" << endl;
    outputfile << i << endl;
    outputfile.close();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

When fixing the path to be an actual Windows path, it runs ok for me;

```
outputfile.open("C:\\MyFolder\\outputfile.txt", ios::app);
```

Comment: one should also test that the open didn't fail.

Comment: @EvilTeach Yes, error checking would have stopped it from being a problem in the first place :)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  What is the difference between the double backslash and the regular backslash that I see when I right click on a file and select properties?  I am an entry level programmer who typically does not output to console or output to file...

Comment: @JerryCarson In C & C++, you can't type a regular backslash in a string, since backslash is used for "special characters", for example if you type \n in a string, it actually inserts a return character. Your code ended up putting a \o (whatever character that is) in the string instead of an actual backslash and an o. Double-backslash is confusingly enough the correct way of writing a single backslash in a C/C++ string.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, thanks for saving me time and a couple of hair folicles that I cannot afford to lose.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the path is not right, you did not escape the backslashes. otherwise the code is fine, and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Others have given answer to your problem. I also suggest you to open and close file only once (outside loop), and do only *file-writing*  within loop.